# Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated. Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, ether

> Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated. Convert the contract to "address" type to access the member, for example use "address(contract).balance" instead.

I am getting this warning in Solidity using the Remix editor.

This is the code chunk:

```
function getSummary() public view returns(
    uint, uint, uint, uint, address
){
    return (
        minimumContribution,
        this.balance, // This is the warning line.
        requests.length,
        approversCount,
        manager
    );
}
```

I tried following what the warning suggests:

```
function getSummary() public view returns(
    uint, uint, uint, uint, address
){
    return (
        minimumContribution,
        address(contract).balance,
        requests.length,
        approversCount,
        manager
    );
}
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`balance` is an attribute of the `address` type, not from a contract. Change it to `address(this).balance`.

```
function getSummary() public view returns(
    uint, uint, uint, uint, address
){
    return (
        minimumContribution,
        address(this).balance,
        requests.length,
        approversCount,
        manager
    );
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could assign `this` to a local variable of type `address`...

```
address contractAddress = this;

function getSummary() public view returns(
    uint, uint, uint, uint, address
){
  return (
    minimumContribution,
    contractAddress.balance,
    requests.length,
    approversCount,
    manager
  );
}
```